# KeyError exception's value is surrounded by single quotes

Tags: python, keyerror

In order to provide better API error, I raise an exception `KeyError` if a specific key is missing in the API request.

```
user = {
    "id": 1234,
    "name": "John Doe"
}

try:
    user.pop("id") // for example purpose
    user_id = user["id"]
    print(user_id)
except KeyError as e:
    key_error_message = {
        "id": "Key 'id' is missing",
        "name": "Key 'name' is missing"
    }
    print(e) # 'id'
    print(type(e)) # <class 'KeyError'>
    print(str(e)) # 'id'
    print(type(str(e))) # <class 'str'>
    print(key_error_message.get(str(e))) # None
    print(key_error_message.get(str(e).replace("'", ""))) # Key 'id' is missing
```

I'm wondering why I have to remove single quote `'` when I try to access KeyError's value? Is there a better way to do that?

I'm aware that there is certainly better way to do that with the use of `.get()` method of `dict` but this is the actual behavior in my code and I don't want to refactor it completly.

Comment: `e.args[0]` would directly give you the problematic key, in its natural form.  The string representation of the `KeyError` is apparently being built from the `repr()` of the key, so it could differ in ways other than simply having single quotes around it (could have double quotes instead, could have backslash escape sequences).

Comment: There is a good reason for returning the string in quotes: if you have keys like `1234` and `'1234'`, there would be no way to distinguish them if they were simply printed. Using the `repr()` of the key makes clear what you have.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper for your explanations :)

Comment: Thank you too @ThierryLathuille I understand better now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `args` field to access the key name that caused the exception:

```
try:
    ....
except KeyError as e:
    missing_key = e.args[0]
    print(f"Key '{missing_key}' is missing")
```